# Javascript Pushing Objects to Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm unable to push objects to an array and i can't figure out why. At the moment, the result (records) repeats the last instance of the each loop.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m1v7x25s/)

### HTML

```
<div data-provider="prv1"></div>
<div data-rating="rtn1"></div>
<div data-price="prc1"></div>

<div data-provider="prv2"></div>
<div data-rating="rtn2"></div>
<div data-price="prc2"></div>

<div data-provider="prv3"></div>
<div data-rating="rtn3"></div>
<div data-price="prc3"></div>

<div data-provider="prv4"></div>
<div data-rating="rtn4"></div>
<div data-price="prc4"></div>
```

### Javascript (w/ jQuery)

```
(function(){

  var sort = $(".sort select");
  var provider = $("[data-provider]");
  var rating = $("[data-rating]");
  var price = $("[data-price]");

  var records = [];
  var record = {};

  $(provider).each(function(index, value){
    record.provider = $(provider).eq(index).data("provider"); 
    record.rating = $(rating).eq(index).data("rating");
    record.price = $(price).eq(index).data("price");
    records[index] = record;
  });


})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loop you set each index to be equal to record. Since the scope of record is the anonymous function, it will be the same object for each index.

What you want is for the scope to be the function provided to `.each`

Like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xfwvsxto/)

```
$(provider).each(function(index, value){
    var record = {};
    ...
});
```

Comment: This is the right answer, i will accept it. However, could you explain a little more? I expected the record object to be re-assigned for each loop iteration. Why can I access the outer scope for records, but not record?

Comment: @Jack: *"I expected the record object to be re-assigned for each loop iteration."* Why did you expect that for `record`, but not `records`?

Comment: @JackTuck: I'm confused. I thought you meant that in each iteration, `record` was a new object. However,  that would imply that `records` must be a new array in each iteration as well. I.e. in each iteration, you would assign a single element to a new array. But, I'm quite certain that you expected that there is only a single `results` array and you are filling the array with multiple objects.

Comment: "Why did you expect that for record, but not records?". I did, but `record` was where I didn't see that behaviour. I don't understand why this answer works.

Comment: I understand why `record` would be equal to the result from the last loop iteration, but I don't get why the `records` array wasn't catching the object which resulted from the loops beforehand, as-being as the array was getting pushed to on each iteration.

Comment: @JackTuck: There is only a single object in your code. Assigning a property to an object does not create a new object. Maybe it's easier to see without a loop: `var arr = []; var obj = {}; arr[0] = obj; arr[1] = obj; arr[2] = obj; obj.foo = 'bar';`. That's what you are doing basically. The same object is added to the array multiple times.

Comment: I know there is only a single object, I made a fiddle to demonstrate what i expected. http://jsfiddle.net/8s6n79td/

Comment: @JackTuck: You are saying that you know that there is a single object, but it seems you still expect that the object gets copied when it is assigned to the array. It's not. If you do `arr[0] = obj; arr[1] = obj;`, then you are assigned  *the same* object to two locations in the array. Put the other way: Both elements reference the *same* object. So of course if that object is mutated, both locations will "contain" the mutated data because there only is a *single* object. Is that what you were confused about? Otherwise I don't understand what else you are having problems with.

Comment: Thanks for explaining Felix, I've updated the fiddle which I think will explain it better. http://jsfiddle.net/mz1ktnr6/

Comment: @FelixKling "So of course if that object is mutated, both locations will "contain" the mutated data because there only is a single object. Is that what you were confused about?". Yes, that's it. I was struggling to get my head around it. hassassin, Thanks for the explanation.